# Understanding the implications between i and s in parameterized queries

Tags: php, mysql

I've just figured out why a query being run from my PHP front end was taking about 50 seconds longer than it does when I run it from MySQL monitor, but would like to understand the implications better.  I'm using two variables, *$extension* and *$today* and sending them to mysql via parameterization.  When I choose to refer to *$extension* as an integer, it takes a very long time.  When I refer to it as a string, it's pretty instantaneous.

Query;

```
$stmt = $db_conn->prepare(
"select from_unixtime(dateTimeOrigination) as date_of_call_origination ,
callingPartyNumber as calling_party_number, 
originalcalledpartynumber as original_called_party_number, 
finalCalledPartyNumber as final_called_party_number, 
SEC_TO_TIME(duration) as duration, 
origDeviceName, destDeviceName 
from cdr_records 
where (callingPartyNumber= ? or originalcalledpartynumber= ? or finalcalledpartynumber = ?) 
and 
from_unixtime(dateTimeOrigination) between ? and ADDDATE(?, INTERVAL 1 DAY) order by datetimeorigination desc");
```

My bind statements;

Original

```
$stmt->bind_param('iiiss', $extension, $extension, $extension, $today, $today);
```

Changed to

```
$stmt->bind_param('sssss', $extension, $extension, $extension, $today, $today);
```

So, I have two questions;

1 - *$extension* is technically a string but it's always composed of numbers.  Isn't it better to call it an integer?  It can be any length between 5 and 15 characters.

2 - By refering to it as a string, could it potentially open itself to any security issues?

Comment: They appear to be phone numbers which should always be strings in order to preserve leading zeros and to avoid the requirement of a numeric type of sufficient scale.

Comment: You should match types; if the column is a string then use a string in the where clause, if they are different types a type conversion is required, this will be slower could affect the use of indexes.

Comment: Hi, Alex - so, if the column type is varchar, I should declare it as 'i'?

Comment: use 's' for string

Comment: Hi, Alex - sorry, I meant "s".  Thank you, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised it makes much difference. Although your tests appear to contradict this view, I would think that the slow part of the query is this bit:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(dateTimeOrigination) BETWEEN ? and ADDDATE(?, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

I would change that to

```
datetimeorigination BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(?) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(? + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: Hi, Strawberry.  You're the second person to mention this, will give it a try in a moment.  Thank you.